# Get Netsuite sandbox for developer

Tags: salesforce, netsuite, sandbox

Can anybody explain me one thing? Is it possible to get free NetSuite sandbox account for the developer like in Salesforce (developer org)?

Answer (score 3):

You can be a community developer and you get a free Netsuite account.

see http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/overview.shtml

It's a fully functioning standard Netsuite account so you don't get One World functionality but other than that you can do all the development and setup you need to do.

It's a bit restrictive in that once you have turned on some functionality like multi-location inventory you cannot turn it off again.

Comment: 'Free' for $3000/year?  Did I miss something on that page?

Comment: While not listed on that site, according to [this thread on the NetSuite forums](https://usergroup.netsuite.com/users/forum/platform-areas/customization/422980-rant-how-to-get-a-developer-account) (login required), you may still be able to get a free developer account as recently as May 2017 by sending an email to sdn@netsuite.com.

Comment: I tried that a few months ago, they replied it was no longer the case.

Comment: They have stopped offering developer account completely, instead they are offering 3 dev accounts per customer which can be used as dev account.

Comment: @SamAzad do you know if the dev accounts are free with a production account, or you only get them if you also have a sandbox account (which they charge per month for)?